# Sketchup API and scaling models

Tags: ruby, sketchup

I have started working on a plugin for Sketchup and I was looking for some help.  Currently, the plugin lets people select a folder, then open up every single DXF or DWG file in the folder and save it as a separate .skp file.  This was made because I need to import .skp files into another 3D program that doesn't take DXF or DWG files.

There is a lot more to the script, but here is the 'workhorse' part of it that imports and saves:

```
 model.import filename, false
 outputname = File.basename(filename) + ".skp"
 model.save outputname
 model.entities.clear!
```

Now, the listed code is contained in a for loop.  This works perfectly, with the exception that each model comes in way too large.  I need to prompt the user for a 'scale factor' and use that to scale the model down.

Now, I have done the following before the 'work' part of the code:

```
 scalePromptResult = UI.messagebox "Woudl you like to adjust the scale for ALL models being converted?", MB_YESNO

 scaleFactor = 0

 if scalePromptResult == 6
      prompts = ["Please enter the scale factor you want to use"]
      defaults = [0]
      inputArray = UI.inputbox prompts, defaults, "Scale Factor"
      scaleFactor = inputArray[0]
 end
```

This prompts the user for a scale factor.  And that's all that I know.  Am I calling this all correctly.  I am more familiar with Objective C and .Net.  Is there anything else I need to do to convert the value given into a proper numeric value.

Now, if I have that correct, then perhaps someone might be able to tell me why this doesn't work in my code:

```
 If scaleFactor > 0 then
      transform = Geom::Transformation.new([scaleFactor, scaleFactor, scaleFactor])
      model.entities.transform_entities(transform, model.entities)
 end
```

Thanks!

Comment: What "doesn't work"? Do you get errors or is nothing happening?

Comment: Nothing happens.  Once it gets to the `If scaleFactor > 0 then` part, the script stops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `If scaleFactor > 0 then`

That is not valid ruby syntax. If you keep the Ruby Console open when you run that you will see the following error:

`Error: #<SyntaxError: <main>: syntax error, unexpected keyword_then, expecting end-of-input`

Instead, use `if scaleFactor > 0`

Also, you are feeding the `UI.inputbox` an `Integer` - which means that SketchUp will cast the return value back to an `Integer`. You probably want to specify float values in `defaults = [0.0]`

Comment: That was it.  Thanks, I am RSL (Ruby as my Sixth Language) and I am still getting to learn it.  Once I did this, and changed my transform to: `transform = Geom::Transformation.scaling scaleFactor` then added a loop to go through the entities in my script, everything worked perfectly.